# Alert Dialog is not displayed when the current activity is brought to front

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this scenario where I have to display an `AlertDialog` when the current running `Activity` is brought to front.

It is displayed only when the current running activity is the first in the `Activity` stack and otherwise won't.

My hunch is this is related to current `Context` which is passed to create the `AlertDialog`.

Any suggestions?

**--EDIT--**

The code looks something like this, the alert dialog creation as usual.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: If you think is related to the context why don't you try passing context.applicationContext? I don't really know if will work but may.. Please share your code to be able to better help you.

Comment: Where do you have the code to show the dialog? I would say that it should show if it's in the onResume

Comment: share your codes please.

Comment: @Cristian Gomez see the edited question. I've got this Broadcast Receiver where I got to display the Alert Dialog inside. It is working fine with the mentioned cases.

Comment: @Gourango Sutradhar see the edited question.

Comment: Where is said receiver being registered? in which part of the lifecycle of your activity?

Comment: okay wit for my answer

Comment: @Cristian Gomez Broadcast Receiver is registered in onCreate().

Comment: Could you please move the register to onResume?
also move the unregister to onPause

Comment: did it work @vidulaJ?

Comment: @Cristian Gomez - The thing is everything inside the receiver is working except displaying the alert dialog.

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @Cristian Gomez - Unregistering and registering the receiver worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: See the lifecycle image]

**The above image describes a lot.** when an activity launched, At the very first and only once it calls `onCreate()` method. Then it calls `onStart()` and so on.
**Your question is no clear.**
**I am supposing** that you launched an activity that contains the `alertDialog` when you launch the activity first time the `onCreate()` method will be called. And if the `alertDialog` is called in this method then it will be popped up. But if you start another activity without destroying the same then the activity will go to the background but it is still running(in `onPause()` mode). When you finish the new activity and come back to the targeted activity it will now call the `onResume()` method not `onCreate()` because the method is not needed as the activity is already created. But it will definitely be called after destroying the activity. So you may use `onResume()` to call the `alertDialog` after coming back from another activity.

Comment: As @Cristian Gomez suggested unregistering and registering the receiver worked for me. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apply AlertDialog code in OnResume() method and onStart() method also and you'll be good to go.
Good Luck :)

Comment: As @Cristian Gomez suggested unregistering and registering the receiver worked for me. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case of me your code for dialog is not show me a dialog box, i change the code and run it was running properly,

i think this code help to you.

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
        alertDialog.setMessage("MEssage");

//        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: As @Cristian Gomez suggested unregistering and registering the receiver worked for me. Thanks for your answer.